# Angularjs jsonp getting data back

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, jsonp, angularjs-http

The console.log within the success call will return the data I want but when I put it into someValue it becomes undefined outside of the success function

The only way I've been able to successfully get data out of this is success call is if I push it into an array and then it becomes a clunky multidimensional array. I know there has to be an easier way to get this data out that I'm missing.

```
$scope.someValue;

$http.jsonp(url) 
  .success(function(data){
     console.log("Data = ", data);
     //this returns the data I'm looking for

     $scope.someValue = data;
 });

console.log("Data = ", $scope.someValue);
// this returns undefined
```

Comment: Why don't you add your `data` dependent logic into the success callback? Why do you want to access `data` right after the `$http` call?

Comment: You're going to have to put any logic that needs that data inside the success callback. Or you can call functions in the callback which will do things with that data. I would avoid using $watch, most cases it is not necessary and has a lot of overhead.

Comment: if I use the jsonp in a factory whats the easiest way to get the data back out to my controller? Or should I just avoid using it in a controller?

Answer (score 0):

Use $watch,because data initially is undefined until success is called.

```
$scope.$watch('someValue',function(newVal){
       if(typeof newVal !='undefined'){
         $scope.someValue =newVal
       }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try `$scope.someValue = data.data;`

not sure what your json return looks like but usually it will have a data object so you must use data that your function returned and the data object in the json code.